# OCaml count consecutive elements in a list

Tags: list, recursion, tuples, ocaml, caml

I'm writing OCaml code that reads in a list and removes any char 'i's that appear at the beginning of the list. For instance, the list `removeI['i';'i';'a';'c';'i']` should return `-: int * char list = ['a';'c';'i']`, because there are 2 'i's at the beginning of the list. I believe I know how to implement this properly; however, I want to return a tuple that includes the number of removed 'i's as well as the new list with the 'i's removed. I know that may sound confusing, but an example would be `removeI['i';'i';'a';'c';'i'] -: int * char list = (2,['a';'c';'i'])` There are 2 'i's removed and the new list with the removed 'i's.

So far, I have the following function:

```
let rec removeI list = match list with
| [] -> []
| x::[] -> x::[]
| x::y::t1 -> if x='i' then removeI (y::t1)
              else list;;
```

This returns the list with the first 'i's removed, but I keep getting errors when I try to include the number of removed 'i's as part of a tuple. Could anyone push me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive call will return the same type as the function overall. So if you change the function to reuturn `(count, list)`, then the recursive call will return that also.

Generally you want to gather up the returned values and calculate a new value from them.

Right now you have just this:

```
removeI (y :: t1)
```

But you need something more like this:

```
let (count, list) = removeI (y :: t1) in
(* Newly calculated count and list *)
```

Note that your base cases also have to return a count and a list.

As a side comment, I don't actually understand your second base case. You don't want to remove an `'i'` if it's the only thing in the list? That doesn't seem particularly consistent.