# OCaml pair int with char list

Tags: list, pattern-matching, ocaml, signature, caml

I'm working with a function with the prototype `remaining thelist` that needs to take on the signature `val remaining : char list -> int * char list = <fun>`. I'm new to Ocaml and I do not understand how to make an Ocaml function take in only a list and output both an int and a list. This is the code I'm currently working with.

```
let rec remaining thelist= match thelist with
  | [] -> []
  | [x] -> [x]
  | x::y::t1 ->
      if x='a' then remaining (y::t1)
      else thelist;;

match thelist with
  | [] -> 0
  | x::t1 -> 
    if x='a' then 1+remaining t1
    else 0;;
```

The first block of code outputs the correct char list if you comment out the second block. The second block outputs the correct int if you comment out the first block. I have no clue on how to combine the code to achieve the desired signature without some kind of compatibility error.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228064/ocaml-count-consecutive-elements-in-a-list

Comment: @JeffreyScofield Hm...but wouldn't changing the function to take in 2 arguments change the signature to int * char list -> int * char list?

Comment: Nobody is suggesting changing the input parameters, only the result. In essence the key is to destructure the result of the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use product type (in fact your signature advise you to do so) and 'hidden' local function

```
let remaining =
     let rec f i = function
       | 'a'::l -> f (i+1) l
       | l -> i, l
     in
     f 0
```